# Import form one file, manipulate data and write to another file

Tags: powershell, csv

Using PowerShell a CSV file needs to be read, operations performed on some fields and only specific fields output to a new file.

How would this be accomplished in PS?

Just to keep this as simple and minimal as possible, the CSV is being written to a fixed length file, so in this example the PCode is being prefixed with "00".

The the real implementation the columns will be left padded with zeroes, spaces and then each column will trimmed to only be a specified number of characters wide.

`InFile.csv`:

```
ClientNumber,AccountNumber,PCode,Amount
c10,a000000001,p1,100.01
c11,a000000002,p2,200.02
```

`OutFile.csv`:

```
ClientNumber,AccountNumber,PCode,Amount
c10a00000000100p1100.01
c11a0000000000p2200.02
```

```
$InFile  = "C:\InFile.csv"
$OutFile = "C:\OutFile.csv"

$InCSV = Import-Csv $InFile -Header "ClientNumber","AccountNumber","ZCode","Amount" |
         ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation  

foreach ($record in $CSV) {
    # left pad with zeroes
    $RR = "000" + $record.RRCode
    # write $RR to file
} 

#$CSV | Out-File $OutFile -Force -Encoding Ascii
```

Comment: Put a sample of what out file would look like.

Comment: Why do the lines in your out file have different length?

Comment: Your description, your sample data and your code don't match. The output file sample looks like you simply removed all commas from the input, and (accidentally?) removed the last digit from the second account number. Is that the actual output you want? If not, please provide input and output samples that actually resemble your input and desired output data. Also, if your input CSV has headers, why are you using the parameter `-Header`? And why are you converting the data back to CSV right after importing? The variables and properties in your code don't match either.

Comment: Thanks for responding, in my hasted I coped and edited from a more complex example and did not edit correctly.

Comment: Thanks for responding, in my haste I copied and edited from a more complex example and did not edit it correctly.    

This exercise is to take the csv output from one application and transform it into fixed width output for a business partners consumption. 

-Header is being used so that I can have a way of accessing the specific column values.  

I do not have any control of the column names in the source data file.  That my not sound like it's making sense but it helps with understanding the code .  

I found (most of the solution) and will post it, thanks again, Rod

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, the field value is left pad then the right "n" is used in the output:

```
$Space = (" " * 100)
$Zero = ("0" * 100)

#ClientNumber,AccountNumber,PCode,Amount

$x = 1

Import-Csv $InFile | ForEach-Object {
    $ClientNumber  = $Space + $_.ClientNumber
    $ClientNumber1 = ($ClientNumber.Substring($ClientNumber.Length - 3, 3))

    $AccountNumber  = $Zero + $_.AccountNumber
    $AccountNumber1 = ($AccountNumber.Substring($AccountNumber.Length - 10, 10))

    $PCode  = $Space + $_.PCode
    $PCode1 = ($PCode.Substring($PCode.Length - 3, 3))

    $Amount  = $Space + $_.Amount
    $Amount1 = ($Amount.Substring($Amount.Length - 10, 10))

    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        FixedWidth = $ClientNumber1 + $AccountNumber1 + $PCode1 + $Amount1   
    }
    $x++
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace '"', ''
} | Set-Content $OutFile

Invoke-Item $OutFile
```